# LuaJIT ffi : How to pass array of string to c function

Tags: c, lua, ffi, luajit

I want to pass Lua table storing strings to c function. So for example if I have

```
tStr = {"String1", "String2", "String3"}
```

How do I pass to C function. I think I have to call ffi.new but which what type I am not sure..

```
local cVar = ffi.new("??" , tStr)  -- I am not sure what to pass as type
```

parameter

Also in C Function, I am not sure how to access the whole data, will it be string pointer pointing to string , **str ??

```
void cFunction(**str); --What pointer type should be used here ??
```

... 
Apologies if I missed something obvious question. But I am just starting with Lua & ffi. so I am still not aware of most of the things ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple example:

```
local ffi = require"ffi"
ffi.cdef"int execvp(const char*file, const char**argv);"
local arg = ffi.new("const char*[3]", {"ls", "-l"})
ffi.C.execvp(arg[0], arg)
```

Please note that constant 3 (size of the array)
equals to 2 (the number of strings passed from Lua `{"ls", "-l"}`)
plus 1 (last element in the array is actually a zero-terminator).

Comment: You'll probably need to anchor `{"ls", "-l"}` to a variable so lua doesn't gc it prematurely. `const char*` is going to keep a pointer into those string literals in the table.

Comment: @greatwolf - In general, yes, one must keep references to strings alive.  But string literals are automatically kept alive as long as the function containing it (actually its prototype) is not garbage collected.

Comment: This worked for me.. Also, I just came across the fact that, if we don't want to allocate fixed size array then we can use VLA using "const char *[?]" syntax and then passing number of elements..