# How do I pass a Lua Table to/from a C function using cffi-lua

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

I'm using Lua 5.4.3 and not LuaJIT/FFI, but with cffi-lua, on Ubuntu 21.10

If the C function is

```
ffi.cdef [[
   void dummy(int* ptr_form_lua, int size)
]]
```

and the Lua Table is

```
local mytable = {2,4,6,8} --as if an array of ints
```

How do I pass that to/from the C function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LuaJIT ffi : How to pass array of string to c function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736827/luajit-ffi-how-to-pass-array-of-string-to-c-function)

Comment: ffi.C.execvp runs an executable, whereas my dummy() is a procedure in a loaded library

Comment: `execvp` is also a procedure in a loaded library ;-)  You need to create FFI array of int and initialize it with your Lua table (the same way as`char*` array was initialized for `execvp`).

Comment: OK, got it now. I did find that post earlier in my searching, but the "ls -al" confused me.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else, like me, was confused by the answer in the attached post above, here is a full working example of passing Lua Tables to a C library.
The key is knowing that Numbers in Lua are Doubles in C
I'm sure someone will let me/us know if this is not the best solution!

--Lua code, v5.4.3 using Ubuntu 21.10

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S lua -W

-- Require cffi-lua, not from luaJIT
-- via LuaRocks, with LUA_CPATH set
local cffi = require("cffi")

-- Load libfoo
local mylib = cffi.load('./libfoo.so')

-- Function prototype definitions
cffi.cdef [[
   //int gettable(const char *file, const char **datav); //Original
   int getStable(const char **data);
   int getItable(const double *data, int size);
]]

-- Main program ------------------------------------
print("Test Program!")

local data1 = cffi.new("const char*[3]", {"ls", "-lsdfsdf"}) --original, works

--from a Lua Table
local mytableS = {"string one", "string two", "string three"}
local mytableSlen = #mytableS
local mytableSCstruct = "const char*[" .. mytableSlen + 1 .. "]"
local mytableSCuserdata = cffi.new(mytableSCstruct, mytableS)
print(type(mytableSCuserdata))
local ret = mylib.getStable(mytableSCuserdata)
print(ret)

--from a Lua Table, where it is necessary to know that Lua Numbers
-- are Doubles in C
local mytableI = {12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89,91,120, 3.142, 2.71828}
local mytableIlen = #mytableI
local mytableICstruct = "const double[" .. mytableIlen .. "]"
local mytableICuserdata = cffi.new(mytableICstruct, mytableI)
print(type(mytableICuserdata))
local ret = mylib.getItable(mytableICuserdata, mytableIlen)
print(ret)

print("Bye!")
```

C library code, compiled with
`gcc foo.c -shared -fPIC -std=c11 -o libfoo.so`

```
/***************************************
  library
***************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Using Strings
int getStable(const char **data)
{
  printf("In S GetTable\n");
  for (const char **item = data; *item; ++item)
  {
    printf("Processing Item: %s\n", *item);
  }
  //not used
  return 0;
}

//Using Doubles
int getItable(const double *data, int size)
{
  printf("In I GetTable, with size: %d\n", size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("Processing Item: %lf\n", data[i]);
  }
  //not used
  return 0;
}
```